# Solr siren, siren.xml

Tags: solr, siren

As siren documentation explains, the file located in `tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost` must set the path of the war file. I have tried with the absolute path, but I wanted to used a relative path, because it is not only me who will use siren.

**siren.xml**

```
<Context docBase="/../../../webapps/siren" debug="0" crossContext="true" >
   <Environment name="siren/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/../../../webapps/siren" override="true" />
</Context>
```

But running my tomcat I get this error:

```
GRAVE: Error running static resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document /webapps/siren does not exist or is not a readable directory
```

How could I set up this configuration??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have omitted `docBase` attribute as solr works in Tomcat without this configuration.

Also make sure that **filename**.xml in `conf/Catalina/localhost` must match folder (or war) in `webapps` folder. In your example your application should be in *webapps/siren/*.

```
<Context debug="0" crossContext="true">
  <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="./path_to_siren" override="true"/>
</Context>
```

Replace `/path_to_siren` with relative path from Tomcat root to siren (solr configuration).

Comment: Thanks. I get this error: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or './Users/blancahernandeznieto/tomcat-sony-prot1_A/bin/solr/comicCon/conf/./conf/'

Comment: I set the configuration:  <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="./Users/blanca/tomcat/bin/solr/coreName/conf" override="true" />